# ros with Aruco Tags

Tags: ros, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I'm trying to use this pkg: https://github.com/warp1337/ros_aruco

I installed OpenCV and Aruco 1.2.4.

I tested the Aruco and It works.

Problem:

In step 7 I get this error

```
[100%] Building CXX object ros_aruco/CMakeFiles/ros_aruco.dir/src/ros_aruco.cpp.o
/home/paulo/catkin_ws/src/ros_aruco/src/ros_aruco.cpp:35:19: fatal error: aruco.h: No such file or directory
#include "aruco.h"
               ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [ros_aruco/CMakeFiles/ros_aruco.dir/src/ros_aruco.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ros_aruco/CMakeFiles/ros_aruco.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

I think I'm not understanding what he means by `-DARUCO_PATH=/usr/local`.

I'm simply using the command: `catkin_make --pkg ros_aruco -DARUCO_PATH=/usr/local/include/aruco`

And in that location is the `aruco.h` file. I don't understand how the system isn't finding it.

Maybe I didin't install aruco globaly on my pc, but I don't know how to do that.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thx so much.

**UPDATE:**

Thx to gvdhoorn now I can detect the aruco.h file.

Problem I get another Error:

```
CMakeFiles/ros_aruco.dir/src/ros_aruco.cpp.o: In function `main':
```

ros_aruco.cpp:(.text+0x10a6): undefined reference to `aruco::CvDrawingUtils::draw3dCube(cv::Mat&, aruco::Marker&, aruco::CameraParameters const&)' CMakeFiles/ros_aruco.dir/src/ros_aruco.cpp.o: In function` cvTackBarEvents(int, void*)':
ros_aruco.cpp:(.text+0x182b): undefined reference to `aruco::CvDrawingUtils::draw3dCube(cv::Mat&, aruco::Marker&, aruco::CameraParameters const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ros_aruco/ros_aruco] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ros_aruco/CMakeFiles/ros_aruco.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

Don't know what to do here...

**FINAL UPDATE**

Problem solved.
i HAD A package that was conflicting with this one. I had aruco_ros-master, I'm testing several different packages and that one was the one getting the errors. They have near names.

It compiles with no Errors now. THx you all-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204545/ros-with-aruco-tags/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dani](https://answers.ros.org/users/30215/dani/) on 2017-04-30**:\

Hello, i have the same problem, how do i compile cmake files? In the TODO section what should I add?

thx so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I think I'm not understanding what he means by `-DARUCO_PATH=/usr/local`.
>
> I'm simply using the command: catkin_make `--pkg ros_aruco -DARUCO_PATH=/usr/local/include/aruco`
>
> And in that location is the `aruco.h` file. [..]

If you look at `ros_aruco/CMakeLists.txt`, you'll see that `ARUCO_PATH` is used as a *prefix* to form other paths ([lines 10 & 11](https://github.com/warp1337/ros_aruco/blob/7c3fdc387874ce0f72a0c11b71f5f98ee5e7c594/CMakeLists.txt#L10-L11)):

```
[..]
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${ARUCO_PATH}/lib/cmake )
SET(ARUCO_INCLUDE_DIRS ${ARUCO_PATH}/include/aruco )
[..]
```

So `ARUCO_PATH` should not be set to the full path to `aruco.h`, but to the directory containing the `lib/cmake` and `include/aruco` paths. In most cases, this will be `/usr/local` (as is mentioned in [README.md](https://github.com/warp1337/ros_aruco/blob/e11cfc3b1b495e129fc4b991151f4c35ebbd7eb7/README.md), under *BUILDING AND USAGE*, step 7).

If you set `ARUCO_PATH` to `/usr/local/include/aruco`, this will eventually cause `ARUCO_INCLUDE_DIRS` to be set to `/usr/local/include/aruco/include/aruco`, which is obviously incorrect. The same is true for all other variables that prefix `ARUCO_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3